# What permission do I need on a service account to allow pushing docker images to the container registry?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I'm using a service account to authenticate with the `gcloud` utillity. I'm trying to push a docker image with the command of:
`gcloud docker -- push eu.gcr.io/abcxyz/example:latest`

but get an error of:

```
denied: Unable to create the repository, please check that you have access to do so.
```

What permission do I need to enable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the IAM & Admin section of GCP you'll need to add the `storage.admin` and/or `storage.object.admin` roles to your service account. This is detailed in the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control#permissions_and_roles).

[image: IAM & Admin]

[image]

Comment: This does not seem to be documented in the link provided.